# How the SQLDependency class is taking advantage of the SQL Service Broker feature?

Tags: c#, service-broker, sqldependency, query-notifications

Since I couldn't find any decent resource to provide me with this kind of explanation or some graph, after accumulating sufficient knowledge about this topic, I decided to create one by myself and to post it as an answer this question.

Hope it will help anyone who is looking for such explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**You will be able to see that the SQLDependency operation is divided into 2 stages:**

1. The purpose of the first one is for deploying of all required Broker objects, including subscribing for Query Notifications
2. The second stage purpose is for the actual listening of new changes notifications

[image: SQLDependency and the SQL Service Broker]

Comment: @RemusRusanu thanks, you can use this diagram in your article if you wish.